# Embedded belongsTo to an unsaved record creates two POST request

Tags: ember-data

I got an issue when i try to add an **embedded belongTo** to an unsaved record. When committing the transaction, I got two **POST** request. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or not...

Here's my models and mapping:

```js
Comment = App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});

Group = App.Address = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

Post = App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany(Comment),
  group: DS.belongsTo(Group)
});

DS.RESTAdapte.map(Post, {
  comments: { embedded: 'always' },
  group: { embedded: 'always' }
});
```

My transaction

```js
var transaction = store.transaction();

var post = transaction.createRecord(Post, {
  title: 'This post is unsaved'
});

post.get('comments').createRecord({
    title: 'This embedded record is also unsaved'
});

post.set('group', Group.createRecord({
    name: 'My Group'
}));

transaction.commit();
```

Then I will have two **POST** request, one on ***'/post'*** wich is good and another one on ***'/group'***.

Am I doing something wrong ? Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have 2 transactions:

- the one that you create manually and that contains the post and the comments
- the store's default one onto which you create the Group

You probably want your code to be like that:

```
post.set('group', transaction.createRecord(App.Group, {
    name: 'My Group'
}));
```

`Group.createRecord` will use the store's default transaction.